# why do my static implicit operators complain there is no body in one class and not another

Tags: c#, serialization, mailmessage

I am trying to serialize `MailMessage` objects. To do this a `SerializableMailMessage` class was implemented by a previous developer ( shown below).

To fix some bugs I am changing from a binary `Iformatter` to a json `Iformatter`. Json has some issues with `NameValueCollections` so I needed to create a new `serializableMailMessage` to handle the conversion.

This is where the problem crops up. If I copy and paste the below code to a fresh class, and make no changes, all of a sudden the 2 public static implicit operators start complaining that they need a body because they are not marked as abstract , extern or partial.

If I give them a body e.g.

```
 public static implicit operator MailMessage(SerializableMailMessage message){};
```

They then need a return value. The only value I could think of returning is message, but this then creates a StackOverFlowException.

Could someone explain to me what might be going on here?
Why is it okay for there not to be a body in the below code but not okay in an identical class? How do i get around the issue?

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

namespace S22.Mail
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A serializable replication of the MailMessage class of the System.Net.Mail namespace.
    //     It implements conversion operators to allow for implicit conversion between SerializableMailMessage
    //     and MailMessage objects.
    public class SerializableMailMessage
    {
        public SerializableAlternateViewCollection AlternateViews { get; }
        public SerializableAttachmentCollection Attachments { get; }
        public SerializableMailAddressCollection Bcc { get; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public Encoding BodyEncoding { get; set; }
        public SerializableMailAddressCollection CC { get; }
        public DeliveryNotificationOptions DeliveryNotificationOptions { get; set; }
        public SerializableMailAddress From { get; set; }
        public NameValueCollection Headers { get; }
        public Encoding HeadersEncoding { get; set; }
        public bool IsBodyHtml { get; set; }
        public MailPriority Priority { get; set; }
        public SerializableMailAddress ReplyTo { get; set; }
        public SerializableMailAddressCollection ReplyToList { get; }
        public SerializableMailAddress Sender { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public Encoding SubjectEncoding { get; set; }
        public SerializableMailAddressCollection To { get; }

        public static implicit operator SerializableMailMessage(MailMessage message);
        public static implicit operator MailMessage(SerializableMailMessage message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think these operators *don't* need a body?  What do you expect them to do if you don't provide an implementation for those operators?

Comment: How can MailMessage be magically cast to Serializablemailmessage or vice versa without body and return value for operators? You need to do that convert inside those operators and return appreciate converted value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That code would never have compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously non-abstract methods need to have a body, and non-abstract methods that have a return type (such as conversion operators) do need to return something from that body.

You're looking at the class from a metadata view (Go To Definition / F12), which doesn't show method bodies, but merely the class members' signatures.

From this we can conclude that the actual type you're looking at is defined in another assembly, and *does* provide bodies for both operators, which *do* return a value.

You're just not seeing the actual code here, just the metadata.

Comment: Now i know metadata doesn't show method bodies i was able to quickly track down the git repository of the class and view the code as a whole. It all makes much more sense now and my solution works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Implicit operator shoukd convert the values passedbin the parameter and return it  as per the type specified in the method name.

See this link for the explanation 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: And a class is a construct that enables you to create your own custom types by grouping together variables of other types, methods and events. Rephrasing MSDN's definition for a keyword tangentially related to the question is not an answer to the question. Try to read and understand the question before answering.